# Issues installing Android apps in Anbox

Tags: adb, linux, anbox

Anbox doesn't come pre-installed with Google Play Store and there's not even a package installer, so the only way to install applications in Anbozx is through Android Debug Bridge, aka ADB.

```
adb install /path/to/file.apk
```

which would result in installing the application in Anbox, which worked for me for installing [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en) and [Snapseed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed&hl=en), but it failed in installing Opera Mini and WPS Office giving the following error:

Input:

```
adb install /home/sumeet/Downloads/opera.apk
```

Output:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
30103 KB/s (4597754 bytes in 0.149s)
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

Is this an Anbox problem, an Ubuntu problem or an ADB problem that can be fixed? Since Anbox is essentially just an Android emulator running on top of Linux, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at the error message again:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

This means that the app in question uses native C/C++ libraries, but the APK doesn't include that library compiled for the CPU architerchture of the the target device. Unlike Java, C/C++ code is not cross-platform, nor is it cross-architecture.

Some apps have different APKs for the different CPU architectures.

But, bottom line, this is the app developer's fault, not yours.

[Original Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/904003/665251)